# Sum of LSC functions also LSC function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $f_1$ and $f_2$ are non-negative lower semicontinuous (LSC) functions on $X$. Then $f_1+f_2$ also LSC function.

**Proof:** Let $\alpha$ be any real number then consider the set: $$E_{\alpha}=\{x: f_1(x)+f_2(x)>\alpha\}=\{x: f_1(x)>\alpha-f_2(x)\}=\bigcup \limits_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}\{x: f_1(x)>r>\alpha-f_2(x)\}=\bigcup \limits_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}\{x: f_1(x)>r>\alpha-f_2(x)\}=\bigcup \limits_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}\{x: f_1(x)>r\}\cap \{x:f_2(x)>\alpha-r\}$$

Since both $f_1$ and $f_2$ are LSC then sets $\{x: f_1(x)>r\}$ and $\{x:f_2(x)>\alpha-r\}$ are open $\Rightarrow$ their intersection also open $\Rightarrow$ $E_{\alpha}$ is open.

Hence $\alpha$ is arbitrary then $f_1+f_2$ is LSC function.

Right?

**EDIT:** I noted that non-negativity is excess and we can skip that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the last set is more clearly written as

$$\bigcup \limits_{r\in \mathbb{Q}}(\{x: f_1(x)>r\}\cap \{x:f_2(x)>\alpha-r\})$$

using braces, so that we see we have a union of finite intersections of open sets, which is indeed open.